# Library to test whether two regular expressions are equivalent

Tags: library, regex

I am looking for a library to test whether two regular expressions are [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962319/395857). Python/interpreted language/Java/C++ is preferred (in descending order). I'm also fine with a CLI program (free if possible, but I don't mind if closed source): my code would give the two regular expression as inputs to the program and the latter would return me False/True or any other clear output that I can automatically process. I mostly use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Utlimate so I would prefer to have a solution compatible with this. Otherwise Linux (no Mac).

Comment: I think the linked answer (cf. point 6 on the list) is talking about regular languages. Many regular expression engines also support more than regular languages (due to backtracking etc.). Which regexp features do you need?

Comment: @ComFreek Just basic regular languages would be enough for my current application. If it supports more it can always be useful in the future though, but I don't have any immediate need.